# Push multi values in javascript array and get the first element?

Tags: javascript

Push multi values in javascript array and get the first element?

Below, I am trying to push 3 different values in a array:

```
var a = [];
a.push([1, 'b', 'c']);
DBG.write("test:" + a[0]); //output: 1, b, c
```

how to print the the first element on this array?

output should be: 1

Comment: `a[0][0]` as `a[0]` is an array!

Comment: To build on what @Rayon said, `Array.push` expects direct values, and not an array.  `a.push([1, 'b', 'c'])` is pushing an array to the first element of `a`.

Comment: @ArcSine, _"Array.push expects direct values, and not an array"_ .. No buddy! It is ok with anything.. `undefined` as well..

Comment: It accepts arrays, but it will add it as an array.  `a.push(1,2,3)` is different than `a.push([1,2,3])`

Answer (score 3):

You are pushing in an array. Try

```
a.push(1, 'b', 'c');
```

to push in 3 separate values.

And to print it:

```
DBG.write("test:" + a[0]);
```

(or, if you want to push in the array like you did in your question, use

```
DBG.write("test:" + a[0][0]);
```

to get the first element of that array).

Comment: I would use this.
Pushing an array into an array and only wanting to push out the inner array makes no sense.

Comment: Simple & clean. +1

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add items from array then use concat. In your case when you push and array into an array then it becomes a multi-dimensional array (assuming that was not the intention), it became `[[1,'b','c']]`.

Replace

```
a.push([1, 'b', 'c']);
```

with

```
a = a.concat([1, 'b', 'c']);
```

You can print the first element by doing same thing `DBG.write("test:" + a[0]);`

Comment: @jhon you can print the same way you intended to print earlier.

Comment: @jhon you can print 1 by doing `DBG.write("test:" + a[0]);`

Comment: Why not `a.push(1, 'b', 'c');`?

Comment: @Cerbrus he sure can, but I assumed that he already has an array.

Comment: Good point! concat's the way to go then.

Answer (score 1):

```
a[0] // output [1, 'b', 'c']
```

By doing

```
DBG.write("test:" + a[0][0]); // output 1
```

Comment: This is giving the right result, but I would recommend to use the other solution, since this is the behavior I think would make more sense.